# Get cell from a dynamic table in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-macros

Google sheet outputs a table when using googlefinance

Let's take an example for that

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", date(2020,1,1))
```

[image]

I want to get just value from this table. I know this forumula can give me multiple rows. But I still just want to get value of just one cell, in this example I want value of second row second column i.e. 1367.37 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020, 1, 1)), 2, 2)
```

Comment: What if I want to get average or sum from a range of dynamic table?

Comment: `=SUM(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020, 1, 1), 4), "select Col2 offset 1", 0))`

Comment: `=AVERAGE(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020, 1, 1), 4), "select Col2 offset 1", 0))`

Comment: Actually you already answered the main question. Example question for multiple rows table is `=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", date(2020,1,1), 4)`